# What anime is this nosebleed gif from?

Tags: princess-jellyfish

[image: The nosebleed gif in question]

What anime is this gif from? Google reverse search turn nothing up.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Based on various image search techniques such as Google & Bing and searching through numberous websites it seems you may be looking for Tsukimi Kurashita from (Princess Jellyfish).

> Tsukimi is an otaku girl who lives in Tokyo and wants to be an illustrator. Influenced by her late mother, she has a love for all kinds of jellyfish and is quite knowledgeable about them. She is the only resident of Amamizukan who knows Kuranosuke's true gender. Like the other Amars, she has a fear of stylish people and will usually petrify in their presence.

[image]

She appears in episode 4 when she visits the aquarium.